# if $p=1\mod 5$ and $a$ is a primitive root $\mod 2p$ then there is no solution to the congruence $x^5=a\mod 2p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I show that if $p=1\mod 5$ is prime and $a$ is a primitive root $\mod 2p$ then there is no solution to the congruence $x^5=a\mod 2p$.

I know that if $a$ is a primitive root then $a^\frac{2p-1}{d}\neq 1\mod 2p$ for any $d\neq 1$ that divides $2p-1$.

$1=x^{2p-1}=a^\frac{2p-1}{5}\mod 2p$

but $5$ does not divide $2p-1$ so what do I need to do differently?

If $x^{p-1}=1\mod 2p$ then the result would follow, is this true?

Does it help to write the congruence as $x^5=a\mod 2$ and $x^5=a\mod p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I'm seeing that you're mistaking is if $a$ is a primitive root mod $2p$ that $\textit{does not mean}$ that the order of $a$ is $2p$. Rather it means that $a$ is a generator for the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/2p\mathbb{Z}$. So the multiplicative order of $a$ is the order of the multiplicative group $\left(\mathbb{Z}/2p\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ which is $\varphi(2p) = \varphi(2)\varphi(p) = p-1$.

Thus if $x^5 \equiv a \mod 2p$ then like you say $$1\equiv x^{p-1} \equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{5}} \mod 2p$$ contradicting that the order of $a$ should be just $p-1$. Note that since $p\equiv 1 \mod 5$ that $5$ really does divide $p-1$.